Unable to upload non-tiny files, streaming music is choppy
When I try to upload any file above a certain size (as low as 50kb), I will get results like ERR_SSL_BAD_RECORD_MAC_ALERT in Chrome, SSL_ERROR_BAD_MAC_ALERT in Firefox, and a message about 'unexpected dropped connection' in Safari.
The easiest place to test this is at https://www.csm-testcenter.org/test?do=show&subdo=common&test=file_upload
I cannot tell whether this is hardware or software (OS level) related, but I do know that it's only affecting my MacBook Pro (14-inch, Nov 2023, M3) with MacOS Sonoma 14.5 (23F79), and not other devices.
It happens when using any Wi-Fi network, and also when connected via an adaptor to a wired network. I have cable broadband which gets speeds around 900mbps (up and down).
Streaming music (e.g. from Amazon Music) is choppy and irritating.
Any advice or suggestions will be appreciated, as this is a daily frustration.
Any other way I can perhaps narrow down what's going on? (some logging somewhere?)

If you've installed any kind of third-party "anti-virus" or "endpoint security" software, please remove it according to developer's instructions, then test. You should do that anyway, regardless of whether the software is causing this problem or not, as all such software is much worse than useless. Otherwise, start up in safe mode and test.

Thanks @LincD., but I haven't got anything like that installed.

You should still test in safe mode to check for a software issue.

The issue still happens in safe mode, though I have now noticed that the very first attempt allows a larger file.

Have you installed any SSL certificates or configuration profiles, or changed anything in the Network settings panel?

Not changed any network settings. I did install OrbStack, and have found that there's a dev Root CA, which I can't delete, but have marked as not trusted.

When you connect to one of the affected web servers, do you see anything from "OrbStack", or anything else unusual, in the certificate chain? In Safari, you can see the chain by clicking the padlock icon in the address bar.

Nope, nothing like that. I only mention OrbStack as it's the only thing out of the ordinary. I don't know how else to diagnose the problem. Is there any low-level logging I could enable? (oh, and I don't think it only affects certain web servers)

This sounds to me like a hardware issue. If only Wi-Fi was affected, I'd guess it was a loose antenna cable, but you say it's Ethernet as well, so I don't know. Since the machine is still under warranty, I think you should take it to an Apple Store for testing. Obviously that will go much better if you can reproduce the problem while you're there.

Is it happening if you create another user and login through that? Or install another system version on a seperate disk partition and boot from that?

I've created a new user, and the problem still occurs.
BTW, the site I'm using to test is open to anyone; https://www.csm-testcenter.org/test?do=show&subdo=common&test=file_upload

Some potential solutions here: https://www.ssldragon.com/how-to/fix-ssl-errors/err-ssl-bad-record-mac-alert/

@LouieLouie, I had seen this page, and others like it, but hadn't tried the MTU since it looked like the 'auto' option would be 1500 anyway. I then noticed that this article suggested 1400, so I gave it a go and it worked. If you'd like to post an answer suggesting this then I can award the bounty.

@jezmck Thanks for the offer of the bounty, but I can't add any technical insight or informed speculation about underlying causes, so your own answer is better than anything I could write.

The solution was to change my router*’s MTU to 1400 from Auto (which I suspect was 1500).
Doesn't feel like a proper solution though, so I'm happy to discuss further if anyone wants to.

*- A single Linksys MX5600 series node from ISP toob. Up to date firmware 1.0.0.214331

This is solid advice - going under the max MTU loses a small fraction of capacity, usually only theoretical or barely measurable. Going over causes massive observable problems.

You wrote in your original question that the problem was reproducible on any Wi-Fi network. Was that accurate?

@LincD. I may have been wrong, sorry. It may have been that it was two different WiFi networks (indirectly) served by the same router.

Then for reference purposes, please edit the question, because as it stands the solution makes no sense.

If the problem is hardware, you should be able to reproduce this easily with  a USB drive.
Install macOS onto that drive and boot and make a clean new account and repeat the safari upload.
Hardware will error on that OS just like your main OS.

My expectation is this isn’t hardware since you probably can download large files (like downloading the macOS installer). Unless you’re in a country with a firewall you should be able to get wireshark to capture the logs of the networking, but that involves some setup and a lot of technical learning if you haven’t already done that training.
I still recommend a clean OS since you will want a backup and be ready to reinstall if your hardware is failing and you’ll also need it (perhaps less urgently than HW) if your software is failing.

I've captured some packets, and while I don't know what the information means, the black and red backgrounds do suggest a problem! A screenshot: https://imgur.com/w5FDF5X and a gist of the seemingly most relevant line: https://gist.github.com/jezmck/71faf42200b54e0fd3daaf759a3841d0

Before booting from an external drive or if you don't have one handy, it might also be worth deleting your network configurations and recreating them (On Sonoma, Network > right click an interface > Delete Service..., and then recreate it from the ... button in the bottom right with Add Service.... But if these services are unique to user accounts then you've already ruled that step out.

Thanks @LouieLouie, I tried just in case, but alas.

@jezmck Very curious to know if you tried resetting the MTU back to Auto on your router and running clean macOS from an external disk, which would help us understand if this is still fundamentally an issue with your Mac's hardware.
